# Sdcard File not open in OS 6 and later

Tags: android, android-external-storage, fileprovider

I have one method which open files from my app and this method running well on every OS for Internal Storage but when sdcard from OS 6 and upper want to open the file then I found an error :

> Failed to find the configured root that contains
> /storage/BE02-07BA/WhatsApp/Media/WallPaper/download (1).jpg

**My code is below :**

```
try {
    File f = new File(feedItem.getFilePath());
    MimeTypeMap map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String url = f.getName();
    url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-16").replace("+", "%20");
    String ext = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    String type = map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext.toLowerCase());
    if (type == null)
        type = "*/*";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
    Intent type_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",f);
    type_intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
    type_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    mContext.startActivity(type_intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: have you given run time permission for storage

Comment: yes internal storage is working fine

Comment: i am asking about run time permission

Comment: please share your full code

Comment: @YogeshBorhade above is my full code to open file and in this line  I am getting error     Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",f);

Comment: Yes all run time permission is done from my side Yogesh

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this on your android manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`